# What is the faster: to create a new array or iterate through existing?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, initialization

I have an array, for example  (in Java)

```
int[] a = new int[N];
```

I have worked with it and now want to have array with zeros.
What will take less time: to create a new Array(it will be initialized will zeros) or iterate through existing one and fill it with zeros?

I suppose whatever answer is, it will be the same in C++ ?

Comment: Try and benchmark it, let us know what you find.

Comment: And if you are going to zero-out the array, there are probably faster ways than iterating.

Comment: @Thilo , which ways? For example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are that you're better off filling an existing array than creating a new one.  Memory allocation can be very expensive relatively speaking.  Indeed, if your favorite language provides you new arrays that are guaranteed to be zeroed out, it is probably filling them for you under the covers.

That said, this type of choice is a micro-optimization.  In most cases, it won't make any discernible difference.  And if you find yourself in a specific case where you think it might make an important difference, you're much better asking a profiler than asking StackOverflow.

**Edit** I'll add one more caveat:  Particularly in garbage collected languages like Java, you're better off reusing existing objects than creating new ones if the reuse can be done cleanly.  As a general rule of thumb.

**Reedit** ... Unless the object(s) in question are expected to be very short lived.  Probably some additional caveats too.  And so back to "ask the profiler."

Comment: The *edit* is a bit off as a general rule of thumb. The cost of allocation with a generational GC is *very little* (I think it is around 7 processor instructions) so the cost in this particular case will not be much higher. Additionally in the general case, in a generational GC you are better off creating a new object than reusing for different reasons: when the GC runs the old generation needs to be moved to the new GC, which might require a full copy of the contents, while deleted objects have no cost.

Comment: Additionally old lived objects are usually  moved to a stable old generation arena, to avoid having to keep moving it around, but if it gets updated to refer to newer objects, then some of the optimizations cannot be applied (in common GC passes only the new generations are checked, but if an old object refers to a new object it has to be tracked differently --usually by just making the old object stay in the newer arena to ensure that the reference to the newer object is tracked during GC. That is, an old object referring to newer object increases the cost of GC

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new Array and instantiating it with zeros, it should be slower. In this case the initialization and the iteration is done. In the case of using an existing array, only the iteration bit is done. Therefore using an existing array and iterate over it should be faster. Of course, we talk ms here, the initialization of a new Array doesn't take long in general.

Comment: Especially in Java, the runtime has probably faster ways to fill the array with zeros than you could do by iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java centric answer, as I have no C++ experience.

It can vary, depending on which method you choose.  According to Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*:

It is better to "**... prefer primitives to boxed primitives and watch out for unintentional autoboxing**".

What this means is an array allocated as

```
int[] array = new int[1000];
```

will have a much smaller memory footprint and be faster to create than

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[1000];
```

due to not requiring the autoboxing of `int` values inside `Integer` objects.

Also, remember that **the creation and reclamation of small objects whose constructors do little explicit work is cheap, especially on modern JVM implementations**.

In short, it really doesn't matter.  If you do benchmark the tests, I'd be surprised if the difference is more than a few microseconds.

Comment: This tends to be slightly more true in Java with a good JVM than in C++: in Java, the JIT compiler can (sometimes) determine that it can place a new object entirely on the local stack.  This is hard or impossible to do safely in C++, and I don't believe any C++ compiler will put `new`'d objects on the stack.  Of course, in C++ you can explicitly specify that they be located on the stack, a freedom you don't have in Java.

Comment: @Managu: besides that particular optimization, the allocator in C++/C is much slower than the allocator in Java by a large difference. The cost of allocation in Java (generational GC) is similar to the cost of stack allocation in C++ (pointer offset, and very little extra work).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it.

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int[] b = new int[1000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        b[i] = i;

    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] a = new int[1000000];
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time to alloc: " + (double) (t2 - t1) / 1000);

    long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        b[i] = 0;
    long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time to iterate: " + (double) (t4 - t3) / 1000);

 }
}
/*output
Time to alloc: 0.004
Time to iterate: 0.001
*/
```

So we have iteration about 4 times faster then allocation new.

Comment: The test is bogus for different reasons. The first one is how you are measuring times, which hardly has enough precision for the job. The second one is that you are not doing enough processing before measuring to get sensible results, which might incur extra costs. For example, the memory might be freshly allocated to the VM and accessing it for the first time might trigger page faults that are costly... I am not saying that the test is completely useless, but it does not really tell the whole story.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, yes you are probably right.  
If we use nanoTime(); then we have 
Time to alloc: 0.004840236;
Time to iterate: 0.001302426

Comment: You should warm up the system before doing tests like this, as David said.  Run it a thousand times in a loop, then do a few explicit GCs and then take an average of 10000 runs of each of the techniques. This is by no means perfect, but it should give a better approximation. One caveat is that the system maybe too warmed up.