# Clear two dimension Array with huge data faster

Tags: arrays, kotlin

How to Clear two dimension Array with huge data faster. we often do:

```
 for (i in 0..target_width){

    for (j in 0..target_height){
          bitmap_review[i][j]=0
    }
 }
```

How to get it faster with huge data ??

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129911/what-is-the-faster-to-create-a-new-array-or-iterate-through-existing#:~:text=When%20creating%20a%20new%20Array,over%20it%20should%20be%20faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way:

```
var column = bitmap_review[1].size
var row = bitmap_review.size
var arr = Array(row,{IntArray(column)})
bitmap_review= arr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting JVM, `Arrays.fill` is probably fastest.

```
bitmap_review.forEach { Arrays.fill(it, 0, it.length, 0) }
```